# Loopback: detect a change in the model

Tags: loopbackjs

My overall goal in the hook I'm trying to use here in my /models/LocatableUser.js is to figure out if there's an actual change I need to update for, and if there is, do something (make another api call).

I have a structure of custom models that inherit from this custom model, and so it works for both sub models when defining the `before save` hook in the parent model. Here's a sample of the method I defined in the parent model, LocatableUser:

```
LocatableUser.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
    if (ctx.instance){  // new record
      ctx.instance._address.getGeopoint(function (error, location) {
        setLocation(error, location, ctx.instance, next);
      });
    } else if (ctx.currentInstance) { // this is an update, currentInstance is treated as immutable
      LocatableUser.findById(ctx.currentInstance.id, function(err, data) {
        console.log('Locatable User: current data is: ', err, data)
      })
      console.log('Locatable User: ctx is:', ctx);
      ctx.currentInstance._address.getGeopoint(function (error, location) {
        setLocation(error, location, ctx.data, next);
      });
    } else {
      console.warn('no context instance');
    }
  });
```

The problem with this code is, since there are no concrete classes of a `LocatableUser`, calling `LocatableUser.findById()` won't find anything, because the actual class will be some child class of `LocatableUser`. The only thing I've found that works is defining this method in both child classes, but that duplicates code.

Is there a way to have the derived classes' `findById` method called from the `LocatableUser` class?

Loopback version 2.22.0

Comment: If you look at ctx, can you figure out the actual class being used?

Comment: On closer inspection, it does look like there's a field for the class name in ctx.Model.definition... but this is probably a better approach than what I was trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I was going about this the wrong way:

In the PUT call, `ctx.currentInstance` comes in as the currently stored instance, removing the need for me to query for that same instance by ID. The `ctx.data` object is the actual payload coming from the call to the rest API, so I could just compare the data coming in from that to the `currentInstance`, in order to determine if I need to run some update logic.